# Разделить многоугольник с пересекающимися сторонами

Tags: геометрия, вычислительная-геометрия

Как можно разделить многоугольник с пересекающимися сторонами, на многоугольники стороны которых не пересекаются?

Нам дается многоугольник в виде множества точек в 2D пространств. Каждая точка из множества и последующая за ней точка образуют сторону (последняя и первая точка образуют последнюю сторону многоугольника).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал применять алгоритмы триангулирования для разбиения многоугольника на части, но триангулирование происходит неверно, так как ожидается выпуклый многоугольник

Comment: Можно начать с алгоритма Bentley-Ottmann или [диссер посмотреть](https://web.archive.org/web/20100805164131/http://www.cis.southalabama.edu/~hain/general/Theses/Subramaniam_thesis.pdf)

Comment: Если не гоняться за лучшей сложностью, задача решается за *N^2* попарным пересечением сторон. Когда все пересечения найдены, подразбиваете отрезки - получится планарный граф. На этои графе надо будет выделить минимальные циклы состоящие из поворотов налево на перекрёстках. Когда цикл найден, убраете его из графа. Набор циклов - набор простых многоугольников, который вам нужен.